# Mounting a folder with mount --bind in Linux. One sub-folder comes up as empty

Tags: linux, bind, mount

I successfully mounted one folder on my hard-drive to another location in Linux with the "mount -r --bind locationA locationB" command.

However, one of the subfolders is not mapped to the other location. I do not understand why subfolder 1, 2 and 3 are mapped, but subfolder 4 is not mapped. Subfolder 4 shows up in the directory tree, but the contents are listed as empty.

I don't get any error messages.

What could be the problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is Subfolder 4 a mount point (i.e. a different file system than the one Subfolders 1-3 are on)? Bind mounts don't cross filesystem boundaries.

Comment: Hmm.. I dont quite know.. How can I check this? I tried to check it using the properties dialog, but didn't find any info. All the sub-folders came from an ext4 external hard-drive, so they should all be ext4, right?

Comment: Does /proc/mounts have a line in it with `<path>/<to>/Subfolder4` in the second column? It might also be listed in `/etc/fstab`, or by running the `df` command.

Comment: Here's the line from /proc/mounts that looks related: "/dev/disk/by-uuid/e5c67353-58ea-4e8d-85f2-f78683d6cd66 /home/remote/photos ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0"

I didn't find anything in fstab that looks related.

Comment: Here's the output from "df -T": server@server-NC10:~$ df -T
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4     152813668 79713356  65337780  55% /
udev           devtmpfs    500452        4    500448   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       203088      804    202284   1% /run
none           tmpfs         5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs       507716      648    507068   1% /run/shm

Answer (score 3):

when you mount a filesystem somewhere else, any filesystems that were mounted to mount points inside the bind-mounted filesystem will not be moved along.

you can use recursive bind mount -
`mount -r --rbind locationA locationB`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already tried that, and it doesn't solve the issue.. It's really strange..